# ms access insert multiple rows into parent child tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I've been trying to adapt a prior stack overflow post to my situation but coming up short. I have 2 ms access tables in a parent child relationship (one to many). I'm trying to write some vba to insert 1 record into the parent table and multiple records into the child table. I saw this post which does something close to what I want but its for a one to one relationship. Could someone provide me an example of how to do this with multiple rows in the child table?

[How can I make new records cascade across a one to one relationship in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106974/how-can-i-make-new-records-cascade-across-a-one-to-one-relationship-in-ms-access)

I'm using MS Access 2010 and I'm writing the vba as a module in MS Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all relates to how you connect the "many" entries table to the "one" table. (Unless I'm missing the point of your question.) This example works to illustrate:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddClassWithStudents()
    Dim tblClass As Recordset
    Dim tblStudents As Recordset
    Dim db As database
    Dim classID As Long
    Dim newKids() As String
    Dim kid As Variant

    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("Database1.accdb")
    Set tblClass = db.openrecordset("tblClasses", dbopendynaset)
    Set tblStudents = db.openrecordset("tblStudents", dbopendynaset)

    '--- add a new class
    tblClass.AddNew
    tblClass("Title").Value = "Calculus"
    tblClass("Teacher").Value = "Einstein"
    tblClass.Update
    tblClass.Bookmark = tblClass.LastModified  'makes it the current record
    classID = tblClass("ID").Value

    '--- add some students
    newKids = Split("Tom,Dick,Harry,Suzie,Mary", ",", , vbTextCompare)
    For Each kid In newKids
        tblStudents.AddNew
        tblStudents("ClassID").Value = classID
        tblStudents("StudentName").Value = kid
        tblStudents.Update
    Next kid

    db.Close
    Set tblStudents = Nothing
    Set tblClass = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peter I'll review this and adapt it to my situation. I've never used a bookmark before. I'll do some research on it